# Fractal setRequestedScopes undefined method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have my ApiController and in its constructor

```
    $this->fractal = $fractal;

    // Are we going to try and include embedded data?
    $this->fractal->setRequestedScopes(explode(',', Input::get('embed')));
```

Transformer

```
 class PlaceTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
 {
  protected $availableEmbeds = [
    'checkins'
  ];


public function transform(Place $place)
{
    return [
        ...
    ];
}


public function embedCheckins(Place $place)
{
    $checkins = $place->checkins;
    return $this->collection($checkins, new CheckinTransformer);
}
```

when i try to test

> http://myrestapi.dev/places/3?embed=checkins

i get the following error

> Call to undefined method League\Fractal\Manager::setRequestedScopes()

Comment: embeds were renamed to includes. So you should use include instead of embed http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/
I think when you rename, your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i renamed

> embed

in

> include

and in my ApiController se the following lines

```
if (isset($_GET['include'])) {
   $fractal->parseIncludes($_GET['include']);
}
```

instead of setRequestedScopes() and all works clear